# radio buttons group binding not working as expected

Tags: angular, radio-button

i have a simple data grid where edit button is clicked and i navigate to a form that has the properties populated. one of the property is "accountStatus" that has 2 possible values "Active" and "InActive" so at a given time one of the radio buttons is selected. i have html setup like this

```
  <label for="accountStatus">Account Status is {{bankAccount.accountStatus}}</label>

                <input
                type="radio"
                name="accountStatus"
                id="accountStatus-1"
                [value]="Active"
                [(ngModel)]="bankAccount.accountStatus"


              />
              <input
                type="radio"
                name="accountStatus"
                id="accountStatus-2"
                [value]="InActive"
                [(ngModel)]="bankAccount.accountStatus"                            
              />
```

when i navigate from grid to edit page the * {{bankAccount.accountStatus}} * has proper value. but based of that radio buttons are not checked. my ideas is that if [value] == [(ngModel)] the radio buttons should be selected.

[image]

as you can see the "InActive" is what is showing up in Label but inactive radio (the one one the right) is not checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `value="Active"`instead of `[value]="Active"`

The latter means that you're trying to bind `value` to a property `Active`, which doesn't exist. You simply want to bind `value` to a string, therefore you need to omit the `[]`

Comment: oh what a simple miss. spend so much time on it :) thankyou. i will accept the answer in 8 minutes.